# How to find the minimum distance from origin to locus of P?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry, locus

*A straight line through $A(6,8)$ meets the curve $ 2x^2+y^2=2$ at $B$ and $C$. **$P$ is such a point on $BC$ that the distances $AB, AP, AC$ are in Harmonic Progression**. Find minimum distance from origin to the locus of $P$.*

$**Attempt**$

Took $y=mx+c$ and put  $(6,8)$ in it to get $8=6m+c$ as one of the relation and then this line cuts the curve at two points so solved these two and got $B$ and $C$. Also I used the 1st relation I got in this process. But from here I don't know what should I do?

**Any hints or suggestions?**

Edit: For B and C

$$x=\frac{{12m^2-16m}(+or-)\sqrt{-280m^2+768m-496}}{4+2m^2}$$ and putting these two values in $y=mx+8-6m$ we  get B and C.

Comment: What does "AB, AP, AC are in HP" mean? Especially what is "HP" the abbreviation of?

Comment: The distances of AB, AP and AC are in Harmonic progression. Here in India we use these shorter notations.

Comment: Please add your results for $B$ and $C$.

Comment: @Aretino $x=\frac{{12m^2-16m}(+or-)\sqrt{-280m^2+768m-496}}{4+2m^2}$ and putting these two values in $y=mx+8-6m$ we  get B and C.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a general result.

If $P$ is such that $AB$, $AP$ and $AC$ make harmonic progression, then $P$ and $A$ are [harmonic conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_harmonic_conjugate) with respect to a given ellipse. That is, $P$ is on a [polar line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) for $A$ with respect to a given ellipse.

[image]

**Proof:** We have $$ AP = {2\over {1\over AB}+{1\over AC}} \implies AP\cdot(AB+AC)= 2AB\cdot AC$$

Using notation on picture we get $$b\cdot (a+b+c) = a\cdot c\implies PB\cdot AC = AB\cdot PC$$

so we have $${\vec{BA}\over \vec{AC}}:{\vec{BP}\over \vec{PC}}=-1$$
and thus the claim.

---

Now the problem should not be difficult to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ end $E$ be a touching points of tangents from $A$ to ellipse.

Playing in Geogebra, we can see that the maximum is achieved iff $B=C=P=E$ and minimum iff $B=C=P=D$:

[image]

Comment: D and E are which points? P is on the BC line as per the question.